# ROS packages for Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu-natty, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was just curious when packages will be available for Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9651/ros-packages-for-ubuntu-11.04?/) by [tjenkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/383/tjenkins/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-04-05

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjenkins](https://answers.ros.org/users/383/tjenkins/) on 2011-04-05**:
I'd rather be running 10.10, but unfortunately I can only get hardware support for my laptop on 11.04. I'm able to follow the instructions to install ROS from source, but I'm still working through how to add packages and stacks (I'm new to all this).

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-04-05**:
11.04 is far from stable, I would wait a bit before you switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We generally do not spin up debian packages before the official Ubuntu release.  Natty is not due for release until April 28th.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-06-07**:
Natty debs are now available from the repo at packages.ros.org

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-04-06**:
Ok, I understand that, thanks for clarifying. I just thought there was some mysterious reason to intentionally hold back the debian packages until the release date.

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-04-06**:
It takes work to spin up debs for a new Ubuntu release.  Dozens of stacks require compatibility patches.  These generally come from the community as we try to stick to LTS releases in our own development.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-04-05**:
Why not? I believe there are many users that upgrade to a new Ubuntu version the day it comes out (it's like Xmas every six months!). Whether that's clever or not is a different question, but they could be saved some trouble if you started building debian packages, say, when the RC comes out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just installed ROS diamondback from the maverick apt sources on Ubuntu 11.04.
I'm using only very few stacks, but they seem to work fine.
Is there any place where tips about ROS on 11.04 are collected?
The fixes I needed to make are the following:

1. The package ros-diamondback-geometry depends on renamed packages sip4 (now python-sip) and python-sip4-dev (now python-sip-dev).
   To resolve this I created dummy packages with the old names, depending on the new packages.
   For this I used the tool 'equivs' with minimal config files:

sip4.conf:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.6.2

Package: sip4
Depends: python-sip
Description: temporary package to satisfy dependencies of Ubuntu 10.10 packages on 11.04
```

python-sip4-dev.conf:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.6.2

Package: python-sip4-dev
Depends: python-sip-dev
Description: temporary package to satisfy dependencies of Ubuntu 10.10 packages on 11.04
```

Then create and install these packages:

```
$ sudo apt-get install equivs
$ equivs-build sip4.conf
$ equivs-build python-sip4-dev.conf
$ sudo dpkg -i sip4_1.0_all.deb python-sip4-dev_1.0_all.deb
```

2. To get rid of some compile time dependency errors I added a local rosdep.yaml in the ROS_HOME (usually ~/.ros):

   boost:
   ubuntu:
   '11.04': libboost-all-dev
   libtool:
   ubuntu:
   '11.04': libtool libltdl-dev
   python-qt4-dev:
   ubuntu:
   '11.04': python-qt4-dev
   python-sip-dev:
   ubuntu:
   '11.04': python-sip-dev

Good luck
Dorian

---

Originally posted by [Dorian Scholz](https://answers.ros.org/users/485/dorian-scholz/) with karma: 391 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9